# Windows 11, native 7zip support

Tags: c++, winapi

Since win11 recently (in 23H2) added native support for rar/7zip/etc. is there any API to use those from c++ ? (Or it's just explorer thingy, that cannot be used by app)
I need this for demoscene related purposes.

Comment: [Compression API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cmpapi/-compression-portal)

Comment: It's an explorer thingy, but you can presumably access it using the shell interfaces like IShellFolder/IShellItem. That's how some third party file managers (that are too lazy to implement their own archive support) do it.

Comment: I actually thought this was a fair question.  I'm sure the OP is not the only one interested in this.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The question is: *"Does Windows have a public API for a particular file format?"* That's a specific, answerable question. It is on-topic, too. I wonder how you read *"Can you suggest a random library that can handle XYZ?"* into that.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Is that still accurate? According to The Interweb™ ["Microsoft is finally bringing native 7zip and RAR support to Windows 11"](https://www.windowscentral.com/software-apps/windows-11/windows-11-version-23h2-new-features-release-date-changelog-2023-update). The article continues to explain that it is available "anywhere," and then lists "explorer," "explorer," and "explorer." The official Win11 23H2 release notes don't even mention archive support, so I don't know whether this is a system service, an Explorer service, or a hoax. Do you have a Win11 system and can verify?

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, in Explorer I can double-click on a .tgz and Explorer navigates into it like it was a folder, but from the command prompt, attempting to CD to the archive returns "The directory name is invalid". Archive support is implemented as a shell namespace extrension, not as a filesystem driver.

Comment: @273K That's just an API for the underlying algorithms to compress _buffers_. This question is how to work with archive files.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some sample code (using [ATL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-and-atl) from Visual Studio for simplicity) that can extract files from an archive file (zip, 7z, rar, etc.) on recent versions of Windows 11.

However some remarks:

1. It uses an undocumented interface `ITransferSource2` (which IMHO should be documented). It should support `IStream` or `IStorage` or `ITransferSource`'s `MoveItem` but it doesn't seem to work.
2. It can be very slow on some formats, for example .7z and .rar. Actually, it should run more or less at the same speed as the Windows Shell UI itself (my experience shows that copy-pasting a .7z file takes very long time vs 7Zip itself). This reduces considerably the interest for this feature IMHO.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <shobjidl_core.h>
#include <shlguid.h>

// this is an undocumented interface
DECLARE_INTERFACE_IID_(ITransferSource2, ITransferSource, "D6B78E20-B98A-49FA-AE7E-2BA7FCE522F5")
{
public:
    virtual HRESULT WINAPI IsCopySupported(IShellItem* psiSource, IShellItem* psiDest, BOOL* fSupported) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT WINAPI CopyItem(IShellItem* psiSource, IShellItem* psiDest, PCWSTR pszNameDst, TRANSFER_SOURCE_FLAGS flags, int, IShellItem**) = 0;
    virtual HRESULT WINAPI LastCopyError(int*) = 0;
};

void ExtractItemToTarget(IShellItem* item, IShellItem* target, bool recursive)
{
    // enumerate item's children
    CComPtr<IEnumShellItems> items;
    ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(item->BindToHandler(nullptr, BHID_EnumItems, IID_PPV_ARGS(&items))));

    do
    {
        CComPtr<IShellItem> child;
        items->Next(1, &child, 0);
        if (!child)
            break;

        // get relative name
        CComHeapPtr<wchar_t> name;
        ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(child->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_PARENTRELATIVEPARSING, &name)));

        // get full path for display
        CComHeapPtr<wchar_t> path;
        ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(child->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING, &path)));
        wprintf(L"Processing '%s'...\n", path.m_pData);

        // folder or item?
        SFGAOF folder = 0;
        if (SUCCEEDED(child->GetAttributes(SFGAO_FOLDER, &folder)) && folder)
        {
            if (recursive)
            {
                CComPtr<ITransferDestination> destination;
                ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(target->BindToHandler(nullptr, BHID_Transfer, IID_PPV_ARGS(&destination))));

                // ensure directory exists. we create a directory even for an empty folder
                CComPtr<IShellItem> childTarget;
                CComPtr<IShellItemResources> resources;
                ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(destination->CreateItem(name, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY, 0, TSF_OVERWRITE_EXIST, IID_PPV_ARGS(&childTarget), IID_PPV_ARGS(&resources))));

                // go deep down
                ExtractItemToTarget(child, childTarget, recursive);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // extract file (here we overwrite)
            CComPtr<ITransferSource> source;
            ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(item->BindToHandler(nullptr, BHID_Transfer, IID_PPV_ARGS(&source))));

            CComPtr<ITransferSource2> source2;
            ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(source.QueryInterface(&source2)));

            CComPtr<IShellItem> newItem;
            ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(source2->CopyItem(child, target, name, TSF_OVERWRITE_EXIST, 0, &newItem)));
        }
        child.Release();
    } while (true);
}

int main()
{
    ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(CoInitialize(nullptr)));
    {
        // should support zip 7z (slow!) gz bz2 tar rar (slow!) tgz tbz2 tzst txz zst xz
        CComPtr<IShellItem> file;
        ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(L"c:\\mypath\\my.zip", nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&file))));

        // target path, create directory
        auto targetPath = L"c:\\target";
        CreateDirectory(targetPath, nullptr);

        CComPtr<IShellItem> target;
        ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(targetPath, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&target))));

        // extract file into target folder
        ExtractItemToTarget(file, target, true);
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great answer :)